# NoMethodError undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, undefined, nomethoderror

Working on final class project. I need to calculate the GPA of my major credits and non major credits separately for a transcript page. When I run this code below as a controller it works fine and show my total credit hours for major and non major but when I put this code

`@GPA_for_major = (course.credits * course.grade.scale) / course.credits`

in the If statement I get NoMethodError in TransController#transcript
 undefined method 'credits' for # Course::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00000007b99798>

```
class Transcript
    def initialize (course_array)
        @course = course_array
    @total_non_major_credits = 0
        @total_major_credits = 0
        @GPA_for_major = 0
        @GPA_for_non_major = 0
        for item in @course
            if  item.is_for_major 
              @total_major_credits = @total_major_credits + item.credits 
           else
             @total_non_major_credits = @total_non_major_credits + item.credits
           end  
        end
    end

    def course
        @course
    end

    def total_non_major_credits
        @total_non_major_credits
    end

    def total_major_credits
        @total_major_credits
    end

    def GPA_for_major
        @GPA_for_major
    end

    def GPA_for_non_major
        @GPA_for_non_major
    end
end
```

This is the Controller for my transcript page

```
class TransController < ApplicationController
  def transcript
    @courses = Course.all
    @transcript =Transcript.new(@courses)
  end
end
```

I'm not sure what else to include because this is my first post but any help will be awesome! Thanks!

Comment: Your problem would be more obvious if you named your arrays as plurals. Your `@course` variable doesn't hold *a* course, it holds an array of courses, so it should be called `@courses`. Then, it's pretty easy to see that you cannot do `@courses.credits`.

Answer (score 0):

`@course` appears to refer to an array of courses and the `if` statement is within a loop that iterates over the items setting a local variable `item` for each course.  Given that, you should use item instead of course:

```
@GPA_for_major = (item.credits * item.grade.scale) / item.credits
```